# Best practices for navigations in landscape and portrait mode in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, rotation

I am developing an iPad application which supports both landscape as well as portrait orientation.I am having two different nib files for my rootviewController. Here is the scenario of the issue -
1.Select an item from root view in portait mode, pushes the next view in portrait.
2.Rotate the device
3.Press back button on navigation bar
The view is loaded from the stack is portait view of rootViewController. While device is still in landscape mode.
Please suggest the solution to handle above issue.
Also, please suggest the best practices to follow while handling device rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use notifications in following methods and set the coordinates in **receivedRotate** method.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}
```

For example in **receivedRotate** you can set your tableview's coordinates as :

```
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft||orientation==UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [tblView reloadData];
        tableX=70.0;

    }
    else
    {
        [tblView reloadData];
        tableX=48.0;
}
```

Also call **recieveRotate** in viewDidLoad which is **very** important.

Comment: Thanks nitish for the detailed answer.it is similar to what iAmitwagh mentined above

Comment: Yeah. But I posted it before :)

Answer (score 1):

check this method , may be help u...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
// Return YES for supported orientations.
return ( 
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 
        || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
        || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
        || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
        );}
```

or  try to set  autoresizingMask for controllers hope it will help u.

Comment: I am returning YES for supporting all the rotations.Can u put some light on autoresizingMask?? how and where to set it?

Comment: its property of ur UIComponent . u can set it to  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight.  it automatically resizes width and height of UIcomponent according to orientation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check orientation at runtime in method
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {

}
& change elements of your view according to orientation.

Comment: Thanks Amit.It worked along with implementing the -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration  method for handling the rotations.